# get a error msg when test myapp on ipod

Tags: ios, xcode

I use xcode4 develop a base map app ,
i set a region use `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` like follow:

`self->map.hidden=NO;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[NSNumber numberWithFloat:34.923964] doubleValue],[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-120.219558] doubleValue]);`

`NSLog(@"%f",[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:34.923964] doubleValue]);`

`MKCoordinateRegion reg = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc,[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1000] doubleValue],[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1000] doubleValue]);`

`self->map.region = reg;`

when I'm trying to run a test of something I wrote, I get this message:

`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_CLLocationCoordinate2DMake", referenced from:
      -[MapViewController viewDidAppear:] in MapViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

what does the message mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you include the CoreLocation framework in your project?

Answer (score 1):

It's not finding the libs for CoreLocation for arm7. Possibly a corrupted Xcode install. I would suggest removing it, then reinstalling clean.